# Overlay not scrolling with UITableView - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, scroll, overlay

I have a UITableView class that uses the following methods to call a loading overlay when going to the next screen. The problem is that this loading screen does not scroll with the list... So if you scroll a little bit and click on something, the loading screen doesn't show (because it's at the top). How can I get the loading screen to stay on top of the UITableView at all times?  Please know that each UITableView is contained within a UINavBar, which is contained within a UITabBar. Here is my code:

```
-(void)createLoadScreen
{
    CGRect screenRect = [self.view bounds];
    CGRect overlayFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
    overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:overlayFrame];
    overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.7];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(screenRect.size.width / 2 - 25.0, screenRect.size.height / 2 - 70, 25.0, 25.0);
    loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [loading setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [loading sizeToFit];
    loading.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
    loading.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [overlay addSubview:loading];
}

-(void)showActivityIndicator
{ 
    [self.view addSubview:overlay];
    [loading startAnimating];
}

-(void)removeActivityIndicator {
    [loading stopAnimating];
    [overlay removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using a UITableViewController?

You should be able to fix your issue by adding the overlay view to the table's superview instead of the table view itself.  This way your overlay is actually above and separate from your scrolling table view

```
-(void)showActivityIndicator
{ 
    [[self.view superview] addSubview:overlay];
    [loading startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: actually... something funky is happening now. the uiactivityindicator is moving location (height-wise). not sure why that's happening but it seems to randomly be higher and lower depending on which table cell i click. any ideas?

Comment: this is after i added it to the superview of the uitableview

Comment: is there another solution to this? funky stuff happens when i add it to the superview

Comment: What is "self" referring to in your example?  Is it a UITableViewController?  Inside a UINaviagationController, then inside a UITabBarController?

Comment: the issue was elsewhere... although still weird that it was only effected by using the super view. anyways i figured it out and this solution got me there. thanks!