# Fixed UIImage in UITableView at top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

When I add a `UIImage` at the top of my `UITableView` with prototype cells, the image won't stay fixed. So when I scroll the `UITableView` at the top also scrolls with it.

Is there any idea to add the `UIImage` view as fixed (unmovable)

Thanks!

Comment: put it inside table header

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10423468/1199624

Comment: @FrequencyMatched it will scrolls too. I suggest putting it in a UIImageView that is at top of the UITableView as a subview of the main view (containing image and table)

Comment: @ryancrunchi yes but if you put UIImageView as a section header(programmatically), it won't scroll.

Comment: If it is section header it won't scrolls until the second section, but it will scrolls if you scroll over top (like pull to refresh). And if it is table view header it will scrolls like any other cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this:

1. Keep your baseview as regular UIView.
2. Add image as subView at say (0,10)
3. Add a UITableView at (0, 10+margin) position.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. So we can use the **scrollViewDidScroll** method for performing this task.

Fixing imageView at the top is simple. But you need to get the reference of your imageView in scrollViewDidScroll method.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView==self.tableView {

        var frame = yourImageView.frame

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {

            frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            yourImageView.frame = frame

        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {

            frame.origin.y = 0
            yourImageView.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a `UIView` subclass and fail the hit-test, thus passing all touch events to the table view underneath which will allow your to use scrolling gestures inside the image view without it moving.

In your implementation:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (view == self) {

        view = nil;

    }

    return view;
}
```

Place your `UIImageView` over the table view i.e. Add it to the table view's superview (make sure user-interaction is enabled and set the class in the storyboard to your subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Set image in UIImageView or add as UIView background in UITableView header, by using the following method. Sorry below code is for swift, you will find  it for Objective C too.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

}
```